# Querying rails active record based on jsonb column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have record named **User** which is having a column called **attrs**.

The **attrs** is a jsonb column. The record looks like below:

I am posting `as_json` record of a  User.

```
{
  "id"=>uuid1,
  "profile_id"=>uuid2,
  "campaign_id"=>uuid3,
  "asset_id"=>uuid4,
  "brand_id"=>"5",
  "region"=>"Non-EU",
  "attrs"=>{
    uuid5=>{
      "label"=>"Email",
      "value"=>"example@test.com.tw"
    },
    uuid6=>{
      "label"=>"Last Name ",
      "value"=>"Yang"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to query The `User` active record based on

`"label"=>"Email","value"=>"example@test.com.tw"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be easier if you had an array instead of key-value pairs in `attrs` column

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
User.where("settings @> ?", {uuid5: {label: 'Email', value: 'example@test.com.tw'}}.to_json)
```

For more reference see..

https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: There are uniq keys in hash `uuid5`, `uuid6` and so on. So I dont think your approach would work

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [`a_horse_with_no_name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55512200/4950680) answer here is a raw sql version:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each(u.attrs) as t(uid,entry)
              where t.entry ->> 'label' = 'Email'
                and t.entry ->> 'value' = 'example@test.com.tw')
```

And here is AR version:

```
User.find_by_sql(["
  select u.*
  from users u
  where exists (select *
                from jsonb_each(u.attrs) as t(uid,entry)
                where t.entry ->> 'label' = ?
                  and t.entry ->> 'value' = ?)
  ", 'Email', 'example@test.com.tw'])
```

You can move it to model scope or method. Or to separate query object.

It relies on postgresql [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) method. I just noticed that you did not specify your database

Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/55512200/4950680