# How to query objects in nested json in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

Lets say I have table called `users` with `jsonb` column called `attrs` with values like this:

```
{
  "uuid5": {
    "label": "Email",
    "value": "example@test.com.tw"
  },
  "uuid6": {
    "label": "Last Name ",
    "value": "Yang"
  }
}
```

Here is a one-liner:

```
"attrs": { "uuid5": { "label": "Email", "value": "example@test.com.tw" }, "uuid6": { "label": "Last Name ", "value": "Yang" }
```

As you can see there are uniq keys `uuid5`, `uuid6` and so on.

How to get users with label = 'Email' and value = 'example@test.com.tw'?

In [`postgres docs`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) about json functions there is a function called [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) which returns set of JSON object key/value pairs. But I could not find a way to write a query based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `jsonb_each` to iterate over all entries in the attrs colum. It will return key/value pairs where the key is the `uuid` and the entry is your actual JSON structure you want to inspect. You can use that in conjunction with an EXISTS condition:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each(u.attrs) as t(uid,entry)
              where t.entry ->> 'label' = 'Email'
                and t.entry ->> 'value' = 'example@test.com.tw')
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SHN95362

Comment: Oh I can use nested query to iterate over `jsonb_each` output. Got it. And there is no way to do it in one query?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky: that **is** one query